# Generating Substring

Tags: c++, algorithm, substring

I am trying to generate all the sub string and store it in a dynamically allocated string array as shown:

```
  cin>>N;
  string str;
  cin>>str;
  ll m=N*(N+1)/2;
  string *sub = new string[m];
  int k=0;
  for(int i=1,k=0; i<=N; i++,k++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j+i<=N; j++,k++)
        {
         sub[k]=str.substr(j,i);
         cout<<sub[k]<<' ';
        }
  }
```

But the following code gives error after generating all the string upto size 3

But when instead of storing the string i print all the substring the code gives desired output.(As per following code)

```
cin>>N;
  string str;
  cin>>str;
  ll m=N*(N+1)/2;
  string *sub = new string[m];
  int k=0;
  for(int i=1,k=0; i<=N; i++,k++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j+i<=N; j++,k++)
        {
         cout<<str.substr(j,i);
        }
  }
```

Please  help??

Comment: Please avoid new std::string and look-up std::string::substr

Comment: `string *sub = new string[m];` => `std::vector<string> sub(m);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much incrementing of `k`:

```
for(int i=1,k=0; i<=N; i++,k++) // <==
{
    for(int j=0; j+i<=N; j++,k++)
    {
```

You only want to increment `k` everytime you add something to your array, which only happens in the inner loop. As-is, you're doing an extra increment every major loop, so you're walking off the end of your array.

To avoid this problem, you could have done:

```
std::vector<std::string> subs;
subs.reserve(m);
for (int i=1; i<=N; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; i+j<=N; ++j) {
        subs.push_back(str.substr(j, i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the help, I have just started about with coding so i dont know about vector, but i will try to lear about it. Thanx again